# Unable to make iOS build

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native

App is running perfectly in both debug/release mode but when i try to make archive (build) it throw error `Could not reparse object file in bitcode bundle: 'Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '1205.0.22.11.0_0' Reader: '1200.0.32.29_0')', using libLTO version 'LLVM version 12.0.0, (clang-1200.0.32.29)' for architecture arm64`

I am using
React-Native "0.64.0"

React "17.0.1"

Xcode "12.4 (12D4e)"

Comment: Either you or a library which you use in the project has been compiled with different versions of the XCode.
Try upgrading your XCode to the latest version.

Comment: have you set the Bulid Settings -> Build Options -> Enable Bitcode NO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue by updating Xcode.

Comment: The issue was on Bitrise using Xcode 12.5. Upgraded running machine to Xcode 13.1 and archived to store successfully.